# Comparação de Datas c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Minha duvida é a seguinte.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso exibir 2 status em uma pagina que seria `Primeiro` e `Alterado`, onde a primeira linha do sql com a data de `2018-03-05 10:24:55.787` receba o status `Primeiro` e a segunda linha do sql com a data `2018-03-05 10:30:09.727` receba o status `Alterado` e a terceira linha recebe o status `Ativo` porém já está funcionando como pode ver no código abaixo.

```
<td class="text-center">
  @if (item.StatPree == 1)
  {
      <a class="ui teal label">Ativo</a>
  }
  else {
      if (...)
      {
          <a class="ui yellow label">Primeiro</a>
      }
      else
      {
          <a class="ui orange label">Alterado</a>
      }
  }
</td>
```

A variavel está como `public DateTime? DataEdicao { get; set; }`

Comment: q banco você usa ?

Comment: mostre também de onde vem o seu item, provavelmente uma lista de itens

Comment: eu uso o SQLServer

Comment: Já pensou em utilizar um outro código que diferencie o "Primeiro", como -1?

Comment: precisa dar mais detalhes dos dados, como eles vem... a princípio, pensando que vai retornar os dados como estão no banco, bastaria ordenar, pegar o primeiro item como "Primeiro" e o último como "Alterado"

Comment: Como assim? Pode me dar um exemplo?

Comment: Se seus dados estiverem num `List`com nome `dados`, poderia fazer assim:`var primeiro=dados.Where(a => a.StatPree == 0).OrderBy(a => a.DataEdicao).FirstOrDefault(); var alterado = dados.Where(a => a.StatPree == 0).OrderBy(a => a.DataAlteracao).LastOrDefault();`

Comment: @LeonardoMacedo talvez no mesmo local onde você faz a diferenciação do 0 para 1 (um método de atualização, por exemplo), você utilize um outro código para quando deve ser exibido o valor "Primeiro".

Comment: Então no statpree eu não posso mexer pois é uma pagina de Auditoria do sistema

Comment: @RicardoPontual Estou testando sua função que me mandou

Comment: @RicardoPontual Meus dados estão dentro de um foreach (var item in Model) neste cas ficaria Model.OrderBy correto?

Comment: O @RovannLinhalis publicou a resposta com a mesma solução que falei, apenas um pouco diferente já fazendo a comparação. boa sorte

Comment: @RicardoPontual, você deu um exemplo selecionando um registro dentro da lista, no primeiro, ok, porem no alterado, ele pode ter X alterações, não funcionaria da forma que falou. Teria que ser pelo menos um ToList() no final. Além de que, teria que mudar a lógica do loop, para exibir os dados de duas origens diferentes.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis não estou criticando a sua resposta, apenas respondi o comentário do Leonardo falando sobre ele usar o foreach, dai vi que você tinha respondido e comentei pq não precisa mais dar exemplos pq a sua resposta já respondia a dúvida dele :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode comparar a data, e se a data for igual a menor data do mesmo PatientId, é o primeiro, se não, é alteração:

Exemplo:

```
if (item.DataEdicao == Model.Where(x=> x.PatientId == item.PatientId).Min(x=> x.DataEdicao))
{
  <a class="ui yellow label">Primeiro</a>
}
else
{
   <a class="ui orange label">Alterado</a>
}
```

Comment: Funcionou Amigo, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: por nada, disponha